# Render MVC Fileresult in embed tag not the physical Url

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a MVC method which returns the fileresult (returns the PDF file), I need to use the same url in  src tag and show it in browser.

For Example my sample code is below:

```
public FileResult GetAttachment()
{
    return File(@"c:\sample.pdf", "application/pdf", "sample.pdf");
}

<embed src="/Home/GetAttachment" width="100%" height="1150" type="application/pdf"></embed>
```

I gave the actionname in the src of embed tag, not is there an work around to get the sample.pdf (File result) and render with in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try returning a [FileStreamResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public ActionResult GetAttachment()
{
    var fileStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Content/files/sample.pdf"), 
                                     FileMode.Open,
                                     FileAccess.Read
                                   );
    var fsResult = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
    return fsResult;
}
```

Inside view:

```
<embed src="@Url.Action("GetAttachment", "Home")" width="100%" height="1150" type="application/pdf"></embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately how the pdf displays is going to be determined by the pdf viewer installed on the system and it's settings.  That being said you may be able to force it to render inline in some cases.  You could try overriding the content disposition with something like

```
Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Disposition");
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=sample.pdf");
return File(@"c:\sample.pdf", "application/pdf", "sample.pdf");
```

you may want two methods - one that renders inline and one the downloads or a bool parameter to determine rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
public FileResult GetAttachment()
{
    byte[] contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\sample.pdf");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=sample.pdf");
    return File(contents, "application/pdf");
}
```